# Personalized message for each unique password-protected page

Tags: conditional-content, password

How do I provide two different personalized messages for two different password-protected pages? I'm able to personalize the default message using the code below, but I'm not sure how to add a second unique message for visitors to a second password-protected page. I assume I would add some conditional code in my functions.php file but my attempts have failed. Any ideas?

```
// to functions.php: change password message for protected page/s

function change_pw_text($content) {
$content = str_replace(
'This post is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:',
'Hint: Tell our system to show you, and it will.',
$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','change_pw_text');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add in more checks, but this should get you started.

```
function change_pw_text($content) {

    // Just to save processing other pages.
    if ( !is_page('page-slug-one') && !is_page('page-slug-two') )
        return $content;

    $find = 'This post is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:';

    if ( is_page('page-slug-one') )
        $replace = 'Hint: Tell our system to show you, and it will.';

    if ( is_page('page-slug-two') )
        $replace = 'Sorry: This page requires you to be logged in.';

    $content = str_replace( $find, $replace, $content );

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content','change_pw_text');
```

For a nice resource on the possible Conditional Tags in WordPress see... http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Thanks, @BA_Webimax. Unfortunately, that isn't working — the default WP text for a password-protected page remains for both pages.

Comment: Ugh, sorry. This was wrong `if ( !is_page('page-slug-one') && !is_page('page-slug-two') )` , check above for edit. Had "||" instead.

Comment: That worked! How does it feel to be awesome?!

Answer (score 0):

This feature was [recently added](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/need-multiple-messages-for-posts/#post-13855482) to the [Change Password Protected Message](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-password-protected-message/).

---

The following was taken from the [plugin author's support page](https://support.pipdig.co/change-password-protected-message-wordpress/):

> #### How to change the "Password Protected" message on WordPress
>
> WordPress allows you to block access to any post/page unless the reader has a password. One example of this might be a school which allows access to certain students in a class, or a writer which releases content to patrons.
>
> It is possible to add password protection to any post/page by using the "visibility" settings on the right side of the editing screen. Simply select "Password protected", then enter the password which people can use to access it.
>
> [image]
>
> When a post/page is password protected, it will show the something like the following message:
>
> "This content is password protected. Please enter a password to view."
>
> [image]
>
> #### How to change the password protected message
>
> If you would like to change the text, you can install the [Change Password Protected Message plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-password-protected-message/). This allows you to change the message for all password protected posts/pages, or change the message for a specific post/page alone.
>
> #### Change the message for all posts/pages
>
> 1. Make sure the [Change Password Protected Message plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-password-protected-message/) is installed and activated.
> 2. Go to the Settings > Reading page
>
> [image]
>
> 3. You can now set the message via the option shown below:
>
> [image]
>
> #### Change the message for a specific post/page
>
> To override a the text displayed on a specific post/page, we can use a custom field. Follow the steps below:
>
> 1. Make sure the [Change Password Protected Message plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-password-protected-message/) is installed and activated.
> 2. Go to edit the post/page.
>
> The next steps will depend on if you are using the new WordPress Block/Gutenberg editor or Classic Editor. Select an option below:
>
> The next steps will depend on if you are using the new WordPress Block/Gutenberg editor or Classic Editor. Select an option below:
>
> #### WordPress 5+ with the new Editor
>
> 3. In the editing screen, click the 3 dots at the top right of the screen.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Then select the "Preferences" option from the bottom.
>
> [image]
>
> 5. A panel should appear. Scroll to the bottom and enable "Custom Fields".
>
> [image]
>
> 6. After clicking the button to enable, you should see a new "Custom Fields" section near the bottom of the page. We will now add a new custom field called "override_password_text" which will contain the custom message.
>
> Set the Name to "override_password_text". Then set the Value to any text/html you'd like to display. Then click the "Add Custom Field" button.
>
> [image]
>
> Set the Name to "override_password_text". Then set the Value to any text/html you'd like to display. Then click the "Add Custom Field" button.
>
> [image]
>
> After saving/publishing the page, the text will now be displayed with your custom message.
>
> #### WordPress Classic Editor
>
> 3. In the editing screen, open the "Screen Options" tab at the top right of the screen:
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Make sure "Custom Fields" is enabled:
>
> [image]
>
> 5. Scroll to the "Custom Fields" box, near the bottom of the page. We will now add a new custom field called "override_password_text" which will contain the custom message.
>
> Set the Name to "override_password_text". Then set the Value to any text/html you'd like to display. Then click the "Add Custom Field" button.
>
> [image]
>
> After saving/publishing the page, the text will now be displayed with your custom message.